# Saving AVAudioRecorder to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to start an audio recording on the apple watch and allow it to be stopped on the iPhone.

To share the information from the watch to the phone I am trying to do the following:

```
var recorder : AVAudioRecorder!    
recorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings, error: &error)
if let watchDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.spywatchkit") {
        let encodedRecorder = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(recorder) as NSData
        watchDefaults.setObject(encodedRecorder, forKey: "test")
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AVAudioSession encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

This appears to be failing since the AVAudioRecorder object doesn't conform to the NSCoder protocol. Is there another way to save this object? Can I recreate the object later?

Comment: As you've surmised, the problem is because `AVAudioRecorder` doesn't conform to `NSCoder`  Several options, but when it comes right down to it, saving the object on one device for use on another doesn't seem to really be useful.  What you want to do is save the session on the iPhone and then allow the phone to stop the current session on the watch.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When you refer to session, are you referring to the AVAudioSession variable?